# How to put Extras to different activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, android-tabhost

For example, i have 3 activities.. I also use Tab host with separate activity when switch tab widget.

1) `FoodTypeListActivity.class`:there is a list of food type i.e. Breakfast, Dinner, Lunch..

2) `MainTabActivity.class` : Tabhost which has 3 tab widget

3) `FoodListActivity.class` : this activity is one of tab widget

I have a headlabel in layout of `MainTabActivity.class` which will show type of food as Textview from the previous activity(`FoodTypeListActivity.class`)

**The problem is;** i want to send the name of type of food from (`FoodTypeListActivity.class`) to set as headlabel in (`MainTabActivity.class`)  and send id of food type (`FoodTypeListActivity.class`) to (`FoodListActivity.class`)

How do i implement putExtra to send data to different activity in on ListItem click of  `FoodTypeListActivity.class`

Now i have the the following code in `FoodTypeListActivity.class`

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {


              if(position==0){
                Intent i = new Intent(FoodTypeListActivity.this, MainTabActivity.class);  

                i.putExtra("foodTypeID", 3);
                i.putExtra("foodTypeName", "Breakfast");
                startActivity(i);

              } 

            }
          });
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just use shared preference.

In your listview click use this to put the values in shared preference.

```
  SharedPreferences items = getSharedPreferences("my_food_data", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("foodTypeID", 3);
  editor.putString("foodTypeName", "Breakfast"); 
  editor.commit(); //VERY important
```

Now to pull the data out in ANY activity use..

```
   SharedPreferences items = getSharedPreferences("my_food_data", 0);
   int foodId = settings.getInt("foodTypeId", 0);
   String foodTitle = items.getString("foodTypeName", "No Name"); //the default value of of "no name will be used if nothing is in the preference file.
```

I think this works well for what you are trying to do.

Comment: actually, i know how to pull it from one activity. Just donno how to send/pull it from many activities in one startActivity(i); because i want to send foodTypeName to `MainTabActivity.class` but send foodTypeID to `FoodListActivity.class`

Comment: Thank you, i will try.. by the way what is settings.edit(); ? i got error on it.

Comment: thanks, i already fixed it. but, when i run the program it shows error 01-09 09:00:36.291: E/AndroidRuntime(15268): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Sorry, it all my stupid~ LOL Your solution is perfect. Thank you for your help :D i Vote u

Answer (score 0):

That looks exactly correct. Now on your receiving activity just use the following code to retrieve your value.

```
    int foodTypeId = getIntent().getIntExtra("foodTypeID", -1);
    String foodTypeName= getIntent().getStringExtra("foodTypeName");
```

The -1 is the default value if there is not value with the given key. That default value should never actually be needed unless you forget to pass in a value using the given key.

Comment: Yeah, if you notice, you will see that i use Intent i = new Intent(FoodTypeListActivity.this, MainTabActivity.class);  this mean i send to MainTabActivity.class but i want to send id of food to another activity `FoodListActivity.class`