# PutEtras crashing activity assistance

Tags: android

Hi everyone i have found an answer on putEtras on this site but when i try to use it my app crashes, i have experimented with everything and have not found the mistake.I am sure it is something small but i can no detect what it is so once more i am asking here for help...

First class:

```
package com.orion.peky.thetapgame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;


public class Game extends Activity {
    TextView tekst, vrijeme;
    int brojac=0, provjera=0;
    CountDownTimer Count;
    Intent i =new Intent(Game.this,Score.class);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        tekst=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekst);
        vrijeme=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.vrijeme);
        /*AdView adView=(AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);*/
        Count = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                vrijeme.setText(seconds + "." + millisUntilFinished % 1000);
            }
            public void onFinish(){
                i.putExtra("prijenos",brojac);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }};
    }

    public void broji(View view){
        if(provjera==0){
            Count.start();
            brojac++;
            provjera++;
            tekst.setText("Tapped " + brojac + " times");
        }else {
            brojac++;
            tekst.setText("Tapped " + brojac + " times");
        }
    }
}
```

And the second activity:

```
package com.orion.peky.thetapgame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Score extends Activity {
    int primljeno=1;
    TextView prikazati=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prikazbodova);
    Bundle dodatak;
    Intent inte=getIntent();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
        dodatak=inte.getExtras();
        primljeno=dodatak.getInt("prijenos");
        prikazati.setText("You tapped "+primljeno+" times");
    }
}
```

I have already found some answers like:
[How to put Extras to different activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782765/how-to-put-extras-to-different-activity)
But still have some problems starting the second activity.
I am aware that the adView is qouted but i do not want to create fake loads !
Please dont mark this as a duplicate because it isnt ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that you are calling `Intent inte=getIntent();` and `TextView prikazati=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prikazbodova);`too early, before the activity is actually attached. Move

```
Intent inte=getIntent();
TextView prikazati=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prikazbodova);
```

inside `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
    Intent inte=getIntent();
    dodatak=inte.getExtras();
    TextView prikazati=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prikazbodova);
```

Comment: Post the new stack trace

Comment: As i can see it says unable to instantiate activity componentinfo{com.orion.peky.thetapgame/com.orion.peky.thetapgame.score and caused by: java.lang.nullpointerexcetpion at android.app.activity.findviewbyid activity.java

Comment: I edited my answer. Also that, for the same reason, goes into onCreate